# Nested Taxonomies

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I am trying to build a site with this kind of taxonomy.

This is just an example, not the actual nodes:

```
Level 1 > Level 1-a > Level 1-a-i
Level 1 > Level 1-a > Level 1-a-ii
Level 1 > Level 1-b > Level 1-b-iv
Level 2 > LEvel 2-a > LEvel 2-a-x
```

But using the Taxonomy module, I am only allowed to create

```
Level 1 > Level 1-a
Level 1 > Level 1-b
Level 2 > Level 2-a
```

Is there anyway that I can create deeper nested taxonomy using the Taxonomy module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the following screen respond to your needs?

[image]

If this screen is what you want, you just need to drag and drop term in admin UI...

Comment: Yes, but how did you do this?

Comment: @lozadaOmr That's exactly how it works - just drag the terms you want underneath others to the right, then down